# AsyncTask Progress Dialog Not Showing When I Launch My Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a method inside my AsyncTask that contains data it loads from Parse.com
What I would like is for my Progress Dialog to display until all the data is completely loaded.

So if the data takes 5 minutes to load, the Progress Dialog should display for that exact amount of time until all the data has finished loading.

I have tried many other different methods of using the AsyncTask and still no solution.

This is very important can anyone help me solve this please

**In my Main Actvity's onCreate:**

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
new MyTaskUpcomingShows(progress).execute();
```

**My AsycTask With Progress Dialog:**

```
class MyTaskUpcomingShows extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    public MyTaskUpcomingShows(ProgressDialog progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        parseQueryUpcomingShowsEventsTable();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**Additional Information:**

When I tried to do my AsyncTask this way it showed BUT only because of Thread.sleep

```
    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public BackgroundTask(MyMainActivity activity) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

The thing is if I do it this way the progress dialog doesn't show if I remove the 
      Thread.sleep(5000)

Also if the data is loaded before 5 seconds the progress dialog still spins. It is supposed to stop as soon as the data is loaded

Comment: why are you setting message 2 times?? @casguapo

Comment: need to see the progressdialog class

Comment: @Paudel i have tried it this way as well   MyTaskUpcomingShows task = new MyTaskUpcomingShows(); task.execute();  and it still didn't work...I guess that was a mistake setting the message twice but i did remove that and try this way and it still didn't work

Comment: @Cardoso What do you mean exactly? The progress dialog is only being manipulated in two places a class outside of the onCreate which you are looking at "class MyTaskUpcomingShows extends AsyncTask" and then it is executed in the onCreate using "ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading...");
    new MyTaskUpcomingShows(progress).execute();" .... So it isn't found anywhere else

Comment: What you said isnt relevant to needing to see the progress dialog class, but i was assuming ProgressDialog was a DialogFragment so it doesn't matter sorry

Comment: Did you setProgress or setIndeterminate  first off so it knows what to display? as far as I can see from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html it looks like show should take params, are you passing them? are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you need is this

```
class MyTaskUpcomingShows extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    public MyTaskUpcomingShows() {
        //nothing
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading", "Loading...", true, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the context you are using for creating the progress dialog.

Try YourClassName.this for the context

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute("");

}


class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Order>>
{
    Context _context ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(_context, "TITLE","MESSAGE");
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Order> doInBackground(String... strings) {

    // load your data 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Order> orders) {
        super.onPostExecute(orders);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    // do your stuff



    }
} // END OF ASYNC TASK
} // END OF MainActivity
```

Comment: @casguapo can you provide your activity code. with onCreate method where you are calling this AsyncTask. and have check logcat to see if there is any error?

Comment: Read my post above and i don't get any errors. For some reason if I should do my AsyncTask another way(the example I provided above), using Thread.sleep() pauses the ui thread and the dialog shows but the problem with that is if the data is loaded the dialog doesn't stop or might stop before the data is loaded...

Comment: all the code that is relevant has been posted. The only other piece of code is the method "parseQueryUpcomingShowsEventsTable();" ....All that contains is a query fetching data from parse

Comment: This is code is working fine for me.. i copied this from my project. doInBackground is called on different thread than UI thread... so calling sleep method in doInBackground method should not affect the progress dialog (as per my understanding).